# Unable to initiate android driver with the right capabilities in appium project

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android

I am new to mobile automation and trying to setup appium with eclipse and also successfully connected a real device. I have installed all the required software and packages. I am able to find my devices under adb device list.

I have created a simple project in eclipse and declared all the right parameters in the DesiredCapabilities method. I have also included the appPackage and appActivity but my error shows

> The desired capabilities must include either 'appPackage' or 'browserName'

```
public class NewTest {
    AndroidDriver driver;
    AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    @Test
    public void f() {         
          driver.findElement(By.id("com.google.android.youtube:id/menu_search")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("com.google.android.youtube:id/search_edit_text")).sendKeys("nota");
                      }

   @BeforeTest
   public void beforeTest() {
          service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
          service.start();
          DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "S51C1LV1C0056422"); 
          capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
          capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
          capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
          capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.youtube");
          capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity");
          try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

   @AfterTest
   public void afterTest() {
          service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
          service.stop();
          driver.quit();
      }        
    }
```

Below is the console output.

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
    [35m[Appium][39m Welcome to Appium v1.9.0
    [35m[Appium][39m Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
    [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mGET[39m [37m/wd/hub/status[39m
    [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{}[39m
    [debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
    [debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.9.0"}}
    [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- GET /wd/hub/status [39m[32m200[39m [90m17 ms - 67[39m
    [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
    [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
    [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity","appPackage":"com.google.android.youtube","platformVersion":"4.4.2","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"S51C1LV1C0056422"},"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.google.android.youtube","browserName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"S51C1LV1C0056422","platformName":"android","appium:platformVersion":"4.4.2"},"firstMatch":[{}]}}[39m
    [debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity","appPackage":"com.google.android.youtube","platformVersion":"4.4.2","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"S51C1LV1C0056422"},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:appActivity":"com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.google.android.youtube","browserName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"S51C1LV1C0056422","platformName":"android","appium:platformVersion":"4.4.2"},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
    [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1536289004500 (08:26:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
    [35m[Appium][39m Creating new AndroidDriver (v3.7.0) session
    [35m[Appium][39m Capabilities:
    [35m[Appium][39m   browserName: Android
    [35m[Appium][39m   platformName: android
    [35m[Appium][39m   appActivity: com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity
    [35m[Appium][39m   appPackage: com.google.android.youtube
    [35m[Appium][39m   deviceName: S51C1LV1C0056422
    [35m[Appium][39m   platformVersion: 4.4.2
    [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"browserNam... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"appActivity":"com.google.... were provided
    [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"browserNam...
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Error: The desired capabilities must include either 'appPackage' or 'browserName'
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:78:13)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at Object.helpers.validateDesiredCaps (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\android-helpers.js:705:14)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AndroidDriver.validateDesiredCaps (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\driver.js:470:20)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\session.js:45:8)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at tryCatch (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at invoke (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at enqueueResult (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:185:17)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at new F (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.export.js:30:36)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AsyncIterator.enqueue (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:184:12)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at Object.runtime.async (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:209:12)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0 [as createSession] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\build\lib\basedriver\commands\session.js:35:30)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AndroidDriver.createSession$ (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\driver.js:29:20)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at tryCatch (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at invoke (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at enqueueResult (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:185:17)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at new F (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.export.js:30:36)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AsyncIterator.enqueue (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:184:12)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at Object.runtime.async (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:209:12)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AndroidDriver.createSession (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\build\lib\driver.js:140:34)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at AppiumDriver.callee$2$0$ (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:293:43)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at tryCatch (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at <anonymous>
    [35m[AndroidDriver][39m     at process._tickCallback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define **AppiumDriver** instead of **AndroidDriver**.

```
public class NewTest {
    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    //...
}
```

Include **appPackage**, **appActivity**, **platformName**, **deviceName** in Desired capabilities.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android phone");   
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "Your app Package");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "app activity name");
```

> Don't include **browserName** if you are not opening your app in web browser.

Initialize your driver like following:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
                    "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Comment: what should i do if i need to work with native app and also webview??

Comment: I am having the same problem. I need to control both a native app and webview.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `browserName` and `appPackage` both `capabilities` then that means its a contradiction , as appium will not be able to understand that it has to launch 
browser (based on `browerName` cap) or app(based on `appPackage` cap)

> > Remove browser name capability

```
  capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
```

> > Add this capability

```
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
```